# controller in angular directive returning $get.Constructor

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive (Angular 1.3) using isolated scope, the `controllerAs` syntax, and `bindToController: true`.

This was working fine in my test environment, but when I deployed the directive to an existing project, the `this` in my directive's controller was returning (while testing in the console) a `$get.Constructor` followed by an object `{}` containing the scope properties I was previously able to access without problems.

Why would the controller in the directive be returning `$get.Constructor`?

[image]

(I understand an example would help, but replicating the environment in this case is easier said than done for reasons I will not go into.)

Comment: It would help if we could see an example. Can you post the code for your directive or create a jsfiddle that reproduces the problem?

Comment: A minimal example of an app using `bindToController` can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/zxxATHj7myW3VdE67T4m?p=preview). I do not see the issue with `this` being bound to `$get.Constructor` though.